# Open Multiple Instances of Outlook 2007 Simultaneously with Google Apps Sync

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007, google-sync, multiple-instances

Is there a way to do this?  I have several accounts all using Outlook 2007 and all using Google Apps Sync.  But in order to access each mailbox I have to shut down Outlook and then open it again and choose the profile I want.  It would be nice if I could open multiple instances of Outlook.  I tried simply opening one instance with one already open but nothing happens (or, rather, it takes me to the open instance).  Usually What I do is have one open online and one with Outlook, but now I have more than two, so this becomes a pain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently this cannot be completed how I want it...  The best I can do is open several accounts in several browsers, and have one open in Outlook.  I can have one Outlook Express and.or Thunderbird, but these are not desirable clients to me.

Answer (score 1):

You can get multiple copies of Outlook running by removing the "/recycle" switch from the shortcut you're using to launch Outlook.

The "Email" shortcut on the start menu probably not going to let you do this (as it's a 'special' shortcut).

If you have no other shortcuts to Outlook to edit, then create yourself a new one.  The default run path for Outlook 2007 is "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office12\OUTLOOK.EXE"

Normally when Windows makes Outlook shortcuts, it's the same path, only with the afore-mentioned "/recycle" switch appended to the end to make it use the same copy of Outlook over and over.

Hope that helps...

Comment: It allowed me to opened multiple Outlook windows but they are of the same instance.  For example, I can't open multiple instances, each with a different email account.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. :(  If I knew more about Google Sync I may be able to help more, but unfortunately Outlook IS pretty sticky about multiple email entities per user session, as it's tied in with the OS-level mail profile settings.

Comment: Yah, I agree...  It's a bummer, because I like both Outlook AND Google mail.  They just don't integrate all that well right now.  I may have to settle with just keeping some browser windows open if I need more than one email account open.  Thanks!